# Can I put a variable in my powershell command? (in python)

Tags: python, powershell, module

I'm using

```
    os.system('powershell.exe "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri Link')
```

And I wounder if you can make link a variable I already defined.
My whole code looks like this

```
import os
link=input("What link do you want? ") 
os.system('powershell.exe "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri link')
```

But I don't know how (if it's possible) to put a variable in there?

Comment: I have never tried it with an os.system command but to insert a var in a string you can do this: `'first part of string'+my_var+'rest of the string'`

Comment: What about an f-string? `os.system(f'powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "{link}" -UseBasicParsing')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define a variable that holds the whole string you want to run.

```
input_var = str(input("Write -> "))
basic_command = "'powershell.exe " + '"Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '
full_command = basic_command + input_var + '"' + "'"
os.system(full_command)
```

In input_var we convert input into a string.
In basic command we set the first part of the command you want to run.
In full_command we add the input_var and then we close the whole line with proper " '.
And then we run os system with the full command line.

I hope this helps you. I use this concept in lots of scripts

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using a formatted string in Python**

```
import os
link = input("What link do you want? ") 
os.system('powershell.exe "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri {link}'.format(link = link))
```